# Why trainable parameters are not considered right?

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, cnn, convolutional-neural-network, inceptionresnetv2

I have tested the "ResNet" block and it works fine, but when I call it in the model class, it somehow it does not work properly? Is it related to the model definition?

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

In your code by default `training=False`, set `training=True` it will work right.

Also, since you are already subclassing `keras.Model` you don't need to again call `keras.Model`. Remove the `model()` method, pass the input directly to `call()` method by setting training=True.

Comment: Thank you sbp. it works now with training=True ...  Actually the model function, it is useful for "model.summary()", otherwise, i can not visualiz the schema of my model.